# index_not_found_exeception. elassandra

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, cqlsh, elassandra

> > cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE twitter WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' :
> >     'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };
> >
> > cqlsh> CREATE TABLE twitter.user (
> >        name text,
> >        attrs map,
> >        PRIMARY KEY (name)
> >     );
> >
> > cqlsh> INSERT INTO twitter.user (name,attrs) VALUES ('bob',{'email':'bob@gmail.com','firstname':'bob'});

[image]

Comment: you have to PUT the index before doing the PUT for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong class at the time to create the keyspace it should be `'NetworkTopologyStrategy'`

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS twitter WITH replication={ 'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1':'1' };
```

And chenge the name of the datacenter (`'dc1'`) chek the name using `nodetool status`. It is case sensitive!!!

In my case I solved the problem using `DC1` insted of `dc1`